# MSGraph Secure Score endpoint no longer bringing recent data, only old one

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

The Microsoft Graph Secure Score endpoint, is responsible for bringing daily security recommendations for each tenants, however we noticed that in all tenants that use the service, it's no longer bringing them, the last secure score it brought, was december 10th 2020.

We verified in the API Changelogs, and the last update in the security part of the API was in march/2020.

Anyone is having the same issue and was able to solve it?

We have several tenants, we are having this issue with all of them, either in v1.0 or in the beta version.

[image: Graph Explorer]

Comment: ok, apart from Graph API, what you notice in the Azure portal or Azure Resource Graph? you still see the older data or latest one?

Comment: In that particular endpoint we are seeing only outdated data, the other endpoints seem to be working as intended.

Comment: Yes, i understand that you see the issue with Graph endpoint. What about the data in Azure portal or Azure resource graph? Is that too has outdated data?

Comment: @Dev sorry, I had not understood, yes, in the Azure Portal the data is updated, most recent one is yesterday, but in the endpoint it isn't, most recent one there is december 10th.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the confirmation. So the issue lies only in the API, not in the portal :)